# How to disable Status Code Pages Middleware for all API Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

The Status Code Pages Middleware is good for setting common error pages for all HTML pages. However, as Web APIs return their own error responses, the middleware should not be enabled in the API controllers. How may I disable the Status Code Pages Middleware in all controllers with the ApiControllerAttribute?

Answer (score 0):

For running `UseStatusCodePages` except for `API`, you could try configuring the middleware like this:

```cs
app.MapWhen(
    httpcontext =>
    {
        return !httpcontext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api");
    },
    subApp =>
    {
        subApp.UseStatusCodePages();
    });
```